# date difference between consecutive dates using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having dates in an array like

```
dates=[18-06-2018,19-06-2018,20-06-2018,21-06-2018,25-06-2018]
```

I need output like this

```
from date:18-06-2018
to date:21-06-2018

from date:25-06-2018
to date:25-06-2018
```

how can I achieve this

Comment: Output in html or Javascript? Structure? And from where did `21-06-2018` come up? Also, share your effort.

Comment: You want help getting items from an array based on index?

Comment: I think you should adjust your expected output with your given input, or make your question more accurate, because no one seems to understand what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```js
dates=['18-06-2018','19-06-2018','20-06-2018','21-06-2018','25-06-2018']
console.log('From date:'+dates[0]+'\n'+'to date:'+dates[3]);
console.log('From date:'+dates[4]+'\n'+'to date:'+dates[4]);
```